# SQL Query to join 2 columns from each user and sort by desc

Tags: sql, database

Imagining that I have this table:

```
user | value1 | value2
----------------------
John |   10   |   20  
Zoey |   30   |   40  
Sara |   50   |   60
```

What query should I make to obtain the following result? (being values sorted by DESC)

```
user | values
-------------
Sara |   60  
Sara |   50  
Zoey |   40
Zoey |   30   
John |   20   
John |   10
```

Sorry for the bad ascii skills.

Comment: Ir is good practice to always tag your DBMS when you ask a question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will take that into account for the next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT user, value1 AS `values`
FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT user, value2
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `values` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really it, will accept when it allows me to!

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`:

```
select x.*
from ((select user, value1 as val
       from t
      ) union all
      (select user, value2
       from t
      )
     ) x
order by val desc;
```

Be careful with column names such as `user` and `values`.  These are reserved words in many databases.

Comment: Didn't test it but it looks pretty much the same as @fthiella answer. Will accept his/her answer as he/she answered first, thanks anyway!

Comment: @FábioMartinho . . . I added this answer when fthiella had deleted his/her answer for a few minutes.  It seemed curious as the answer was correct, although I'm not sure if all databases support the `order by` in that query.  (And most do not support the backticks.)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only 2 fields that you're querying, a self union is definitely possible, you can however look at [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) :

```
SELECT [user], [values]
FROM
    (SELECT name as [user], value1, value2 FROM TABLE_TABLE) t
UNPIVOT
    ([values] FOR [label] IN ([value1], [value2])) u
    ORDER BY [values] desc
```

The table I used for this had the structure :

```
name varchar(5),
value1 int,
value2 int
```